# Active record query with condition on instance, using foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 2 models:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :discount
end
```

Products table has several columns, among which an integer: price_cents.

```
class Discount < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :products
end
```

Discounts table has several columns, among which a float: saving.

Thus I can manipulate product prices through: product_instance.price_cents and product_instance.discount.saving

Now I want to get products where prices < params[:max_price]. For all products, whether a discount is applied or not. I tried few things, my last miserable attempt is :

```
Product.joins(:discount).where('price_cents <= ?', params[:max_price].to_i * 100 / (1 - (self.discounts.saving || 0)))
```

I don't know how to reach discount.saving in ActiveRecord query involving products.

Please note I don't want to achieve this with `@products.select { |product| ... }` or other methods, as I am chaining queries from a search form. I need to keep ActiveRecord relation.

Comment: I do not understand why you try to apply discount to `max_price`: if I want to find all products which have price less then 10$, and store has two: one is 10$ with discount (old price without 20$ discount 50%) and another one with price 5$ without discount. In our case we do not return first one. I think you must calculate price of product with discount and after it apply filter.

Comment: discount is applied to product_instance.price_cents, not to max_price. In my question, max_price is the input from the user. I want to get all products less than a max_price entered by the user. I agree with the expected result of your example. When you say: first calculate price of product : at which level ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try next:

```
products_with_discount = Product.joins(:discount).where('(price_cents *(1 - discounts.saving)) <= ?', params[:max_price].to_i )
products_without_discount = Product.where.not(id: 
products_with_discounts).where('price_cents < ?', param[:max_price].to_i)
products_with_discounts + products_without_discounts
```

It is not best the solution (also I am not sure about syntax and maybe calculation in sql not correct, but main point I think will be clear.) But it is simple (another one using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` but it require more complicated sql and it will be depend by DB).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I spent quite a lot of time on this one. Your answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how to reach discount.saving in ActiveRecord query involving products.

When you join to the discounts table, you can reach `saving` directly --- just use the word "saving":

```
Product
  .joins(:discount)
  .where("price_cents * (1 - saving) < ?", params[:max_price].to_i)
```

It's not clear to me whether max_price is in cents or dollars, but you can adjust accordingly --- the point is that `saving` can be referenced directly in the query as `saving`.

Note that `joins` uses `INNER JOIN` by default, so you'll only get products that have an associated `Discount` in the database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nathan. I ticked the one above simply as it was the first. Both answers are close, even if yours also shows "discounts.saving" is not necessary and saving is sufficient.